# Jersey REST GET is working but PUT not. The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource

Tags: rest, jersey, put, http-status-code-405

I've been breaking my head over this for a few days now. This little sniplet is working fine (using Jersey 2.26-b03 on Tomcat).

```
@GET
@Path("/{code}")
public Response update(@PathParam("code") String code) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}

curl -i -X GET http://localhost:18270/nyx/rest/servervirtueel/SVM0000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Followed by a bunch of Jersey tracing I enabled. But if I only change the GET to a PUT (exactly the same method, just change the annotation):

```
@PUT
@Path("/{code}")
public Response update(@PathParam("code") String code) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}

curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:18270/nyx/rest/servervirtueel/SVM0000
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Followed by HTML telling me that the "The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource". However, POST does work (changing the annotation again).

Comment: I hope you that you are recompiling the code after changing `@PUT` annotation and deploying it to tomcat!. For me it;s working well with jersey `2.26` on tomcat `8.5.11`.

Comment: Yeah I agree this is not reproducible with the information you've provided.

Comment: Of course, a thousand times already. And of course changing it to POST after that worked, so I know what I am doing. I'm using Tomcat 7.0.75. But I have taken it one step further and written a vanilla servlet overriding doGet doPut doPost and doDelete. There also PUT and DELETE are not working, the others are. So it seems to be a Tomcat thing, not Jersey. But setting the readonly and web-resource-collection's http-method does not solve it. And at the moment this is all the info I have, I wish I knew more than what I'm seeing.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but try sending a body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the OWASP method whitelist valve was configured on Tomcat (Catalina) level to only allow GET and POST; this is a webapp that held only SOAP services until now. You do not see this in either web.xml's or server.xml, but it's in Catalina/localhost/webappname.xml.